# how to remove tomcat8 from kubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, netbeans, tomcat

I have installed tomcat8 to using instructions from this website https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04
But now I can't set up server in netbeans IDE for this tomcat8. 
I have researched ubuntu forum and found out I have to have tomcat7 to successfully running in netbeans.

P.S. I have installed tomcat7 from ubuntu repo but it failed to start. I think because tomcat8 doesn't allow it to do.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the installation via if you have used [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04) steps to install tomcat8

```
sudo initctl stop tomcat
sudo rm -r /opt/tomcat
sudo rm /etc/init/tomcat.conf
sudo initctl reload-configuration
```

Now, to be sure, install tomcat7 again.